# how to make a dynamic grid view using marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am new to marionette and I wanted to create a dynamic grid-like structure with two columns and multiple rows. I am really stuck on how to create exactly two columns, and have a grid-like structure.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share your tries?

Answer (score 1):

The better way - use CompositeView

```
// A Grid Row
var GridRow = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#row-template",
    tagName: "tr"
});

// The grid view
var GridView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    template: "#grid-template",
    itemView: GridRow,
});
```

Look this example http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/me4NK/

Comment: Thanks @Vasil Vanchuk i tried this method and it worked .. :)